# Memory issue with cv.imread

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I trying to read a large number (54K) of 512x512x3 .png images into an array to create a dataset afterwards and feed to a Keras model. I am using the code below, however I am getting the cv2.OutofMemory error (at around image 50K...) pointing to the fourth line of my code. I have been reading a bit about it, and: I am using the 64bit version, and the images can not be resized as it is a fixed input representation. Is there anything that can be done from a memory management side of things to make it work?

'''
#Images (512x512x3)
X_data = []
files = glob.glob ('C:\Users\77901677\Projects\images1\*.png')
for myFile in files:
image = cv2.imread (myFile)
X_data.append (image)

```
dataset_image = np.array(X_data)

# Annontations (multilabel) 512x512x2
Y_data = []
files = glob.glob ('C:\\Users\\77901677\\Projects\\annotations1\\*.png')
for myFile in files:
    mask = cv2.imread (myFile)
    # Gets rid of first channel which is empty
    mask = mask[:,:,1:]
    Y_data.append (mask)
dataset_mask = np.array(Y_data)
```

'''

Any ideas or advices are welcome

Comment: Quick and dirty could be to stop loading before the error? Dropping ~10% of your data shouldn't affect you too badly...

Comment: Thanks for the reponse @Julien. Yeah, that's a good point and will definitely do it if nothing better comes up :)

Comment: Don't load all your images in memory at once. See https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-load-large-datasets-from-directories-for-deep-learning-with-keras/

Comment: Hi @Miki, this is a good idea too. However, having a look at the image_dataset_from_directory I am not sure that its 'labels' argument can support my use case. I am looking to do multilabel semantic segmentation, so my labels are 512x512x2 with each pixel containing two classes.

Comment: https://keras.io/examples/vision/oxford_pets_image_segmentation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the memory by cutting one of your variables, because you have 2x the array at the moment.

You could use `yield` for this, thus creating a generator, which will only load your file one at a time, instead of storing it all in an auxiliary variable.

```
def myGenerator():
    files = glob.glob ('C:\\Users\\77901677\\Projects\\annotations1\\*.png')
    for myFile in files:
        mask = cv2.imread (myFile)
        # Gets rid of first channel which is empty
        yield mask[:,:,1:]

# initialise your numpy array here
yData = np.zeros(NxHxWxC)

# initialise the generator
mygenerator = myGenerator() # create a generator
for I, data in enumerate(myGenerator):
    yData[I,::] = data # load the data
```

But, this is not optimal for you. If you plan to train a model in the next step, you will have memory issues for sure. In keras, you can additionally implement a Keras Sequence Generator, which will load your files in batches (similarly to this yield generator) to your model in the training stage. I recommend this article [here](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly), which demonstrates an easy implementation of it, it's what I use for my keras/tf model pipelines.

It's good practice to use generators when feeding our models large amounts of data.

Comment: Thank you Dinis, this is really useful.

Comment: I have just started implementing this, and while the methodology makes sense, this applies to image classification. It is a challenge to adapt it from single image classification, with labels 1, 2...etc >>> labels {'id-1': 0, 'id-2': 1, 'id-3': 2, 'id-4': 1} to my case with (multi) labels 512x512x2, that also needs some preprocessing (which I do in the for loop above). I am now working to shape this into a format that can be passed to the dict above and continue with the methodolgy. Any advice would be appreciated.